# Duplicate placeholder on the same page

Tags: python, django, django-cms

In Django CMS how can you display the content of the same placeholder twice on the same page?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
{% placeholder "image_slider_1" %}
{% show_placeholder "image_slider_1" request.current_page %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you don't populate the placeholder, show_placeholder throws a 'placeholder not found' error.

Comment: So what's the solution before you've populated the placeholder? Will it populate from the "or" section? of {% placeholder "image_slider_1" or %}...{% endplaceholder %}

Comment: I just tried this and in 2017 the example in the question works fine, Django 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a page ID for this page in the djangocms-admin backend and use the show_placholder tag in combination with the ID

`{% show_placeholder "image_slider_1" "my_page_id" %}`